# Cordova-plugin-geofence plugin not works in android

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, geofencing, android-geofence

I have added this below plugin for geofencing in ionic. But it works fine in IOS, not in android.
Can you please help me. Notification not coming up when we enter or exit from geozone.

https://github.com/compelling/cordova-plugin-geofence

Comment: What Device are you testing on?

Comment: emulator PIXEL 3 API 29 and REAL ME 3